# OpenERP - Show child_ids invoices of a partner

Tags: openerp-7

I'd like to show invoices adressed to child partner in the parent partner form view.

I've already a inherited res_partner model as follow :

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'invoice_ids': fields.one2many('account.invoice', 'partner_id', 'Invoices'),
}
```

And a view displaying invoices as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>

<!--  Partners inherited form -->
<record id="view_history_partner_info_form" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">res.partner.cap_history.form.inherit</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
  <field name="model">res.partner</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <page string="Accounting" position="after" version="7.0">
      <page string="History" name="cap_history_tab">
        <group name="grp_invoice_history" string="Invoices History">
          <field name="invoice_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
            <tree string="Partner Invoices"  create="false" delete="false">
              <field name="number" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="origin" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="name" string="Reference" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="date_invoice" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="x_category" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="state" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="payment_term" readonly="True"/>
              <field name="amount_total" readonly="True"/>
            </tree>
          </field>
        </group>
      </page>
    </page>
  </field>
</record>
```

With this code I can see invoices that are directly adressed to a company or a person on their respective form view.
But if an invoice is adressed to person, and none is adressed to the parent company, when I am on the company form view, I won't see the invoice adressed to the child contact.

Is there a way to make visible the contact's invoice in the parent partner form view ?

Thank you for your help !

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a new field, `all_invoice_ids`, as a function field, and then have the function return both the contents of `invoice_ids`, plus the contents of any child's `invoice_ids`.

Something like this (untested):

```
    'all_invoice_ids': fields.function(
        _get_invoice_ids,
        type='one2many',
        obj='account.invoice',
        method=True,
        string='Invoices',
        ),
```

and `_get_invoice_ids` (which should be defined before `columns`) like this (also untested):

```
def _get_invoice_ids(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids] # in case an id was passed in directly
    for main_partner in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        main_invoices = main_partner.invoice_ids or [] # in case it was False
        invoices = [inv.id for inv in main_invoices]
        for child_partner in main_partner.child_ids:
            child_invoices = child_partner.invoice_ids or []
            invoices.extend([inv.id for inv in child_invoices])
        # at this point we should have all the invoice ids
        # use a set to get rid of duplicates
        invoices = list(set(invoices))
        # and store in res to be returned
        res[main_partner.id] = invoices
    return res
```

Comment: Cheers Ethan, I'll give a try and let you know asap.

Comment: @renard: Don't forget to change the `xml` file to reference `all_invoice_ids` and not `invoice_ids` (like I forgot to in my answer ;) .